# renaming add_index :name in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm doing some refactoring and so I'm renaming a model `Affiliate` to `User`.

I already renamed the database to `users` but I see the names of the indexes are still referencing to affiliates i.e. `index_affiliates_on_approved`.

```
add_index "users", ["approved"], :name => "index_affiliates_on_approved"
add_index "users", ["confirmation_token"], :name => "index_affiliates_on_confirmation_token", :unique => true
add_index "users", ["email"], :name => "index_affiliates_on_email", :unique => true
add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], :name => "index_affiliates_on_reset_password_token", :unique => true
```

I'm not familiar at all with what names means here to indexes. What would be the best way to rename those? Is it safe to run a migration deleting the indexes and creating them again without loosing any data?

I'm reading here but can't find any reference to rename indexes names. 
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html

Answer (score 0):

You can remove then add the indexes without any data loss.